# Mongo db / C# - How to do bounding box queries?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

Per title - I am using the official mongodb driver and I am looking to get all POIs within the given bounding box.

So far I have:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = _MongoDatabase.GetCollection("pois");

BsonArray lowerLeftDoc = new BsonArray(new[] { lowerLeft.Lon, lowerLeft.Lat});
BsonArray upperRightDoc = new BsonArray(new[] { upperRight.Lon, upperRight.Lat});

BsonDocument locDoc = new BsonDocument 
{
   { "$within", new BsonArray(new[] { lowerLeftDoc, upperRightDoc})}
};

BsonDocument queryDoc = new BsonDocument { { "loc", locDoc }};

IList<TrafficUpdate> updates = new List<TrafficUpdate>();
var results = collection.Find(new QueryDocument(queryDoc)).SetLimit(limit);
foreach (BsonDocument t in results)
{
}
```

Unfortunatelly this doesnt work. I get:

> QueryFailure flag was unknown $within type: 0 (response was { "$err" :
>   "unknown $within type: 0", "code" : 13058 }).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you didnt specify which geo operation you wanted to use. You only specified `$within` but missed `where`. you must specify `$within` along with `$box` (bounding box) , `$polygon` , `$center` or `$centerSphere` / `$nearSphere`.

This is the correct mongo syntax to run `$box` queries

```
> box = [[40.73083, -73.99756], [40.741404,  -73.988135]]
> db.places.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$box" : box}}})
```

i am not sure about the c# mongodb  syntax. But if you include '$box', it ll work

Comment: Thanks mate - i was starting to think that the driver doesnt support this!

Comment: @Yannis, have you tried this..  `BsonDocument locDoc = new BsonDocument {
                { "$within", {"$box" ,new BsonArray(new[] { lowerLeftDoc, upperRightDoc})}}`
            };

Comment: or you can try mongodb-csharp official forum http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-csharp..

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the Query builder for this query:

```
var query = Query.Within("loc", lowerLeft.Lon, lowerLeft.Lat,
    upperRight.Lon, upperRight.Lat);
```

and let the query builder worry about the nitty gritty details of creating a properly formed query.